# Multiplex different TTYs with a single instance of screen

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, tty, serial-port, terminal-multiplexer

I use screen to connect to devices via RS232 with a USB-serial dongle. Currently, I use this command to invoke screen (where `115200` is my baud-rate):

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

Usually, I have more than one device (`/dev/ttyUSB0` and `/dev/ttyUSB1`). Sometimes their baud-rate differs. Currently, I open a new terminal emulator and run screen for each instance, but that kind of defeats the purpose of screen. Can I access both devices in a single instance of screen?

I'm thinking this would involve launching screen with no arguments and then attaching the session to a TTY with a specified baud-rate after it is created, but I don't see a command to change TTYs within a session. I know tmux can do that, but I'd rather stick with screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've launched `screen`, you can use its internal `screen` command to attach windows to additional terminal devices. Type <kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to get the prompt, then use

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB1 ######
```

where `######` is this device's baud-rate. You can also put these commands in your `.screenrc` to attach the devices automatically when you start `screen`, or you could bind a keystroke to this command to get a shortcut.

See the [Window Types](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Window-Types) section of the `screen` manual.

Comment: doesn't that spawn an instance of screen within screen?

Comment: No, it's just the command to open a new window. It's the same as the `C-a c` command.